# XBMC: How to share only the librarys between 2 PCs?

Tags: mysql, kodi

So that's it, how do I do that?
I mean, yes, I know how to share my library between 2 or more PCs but it also shares the Watch states and resume points and I don't want that. I want to share the library but also want that both machines have diferent resume points and watch states cause I don't use the 2 computers. Is there a way? If I create another user on the SQL database it will work?

Comment: Forget about SQL databases. Go simple and just add the media sources to both PCs.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The same way you do it for one PC. It'll take some manual updating if you add new sources though.